# How to re-order the thumbnails for an application that appear in the taskbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, window, taskbar

Assume you have multiple windows in an application, and all of them are set to display in the taskbar. Mousing over the application's icon results in a set of thumbnails, one for each window. If there are enough windows, Windows 7 switches this to a tall, scrollable list of the windows by name.

I want to re-order this "thumbnail" list programmatically, as there is a certain window I want to be 2nd from the top of the list. How can I do this?

Note that I cannot change the order of creation of the windows (which would be one solution, but unfortunately not one I can leverage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it turns out this is pretty simple, and I was wrong.

All you need to do is set `ShowInTaskbar`, for all the `Window` objects you wish to re-order, to `false`. Then set it back to `true`, in the exact order you wish the windows to appear.
No re-creation of the `Window` object is necessary.

In my case, during re-ordering, the windows blinked once. This *might* have something to do with my current GFX driver.

*NOTE: Tested and working with Windows 7 and Windows 10.*

Example:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Window winA = new Window();
        Window winB = new Window();
        Window winC = new Window();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            winA.Title = "A";    
            winB.Title = "B";
            winC.Title = "C";

            winB.Show();
            winA.Show();
            winC.Show();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            winB.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            winA.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            winC.ShowInTaskbar = false;

            winA.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            winB.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            winC.ShowInTaskbar = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it does work in Windows 7 as well. And I'm not seeing the flicker you mention. But in any case, a good, simple solution.

Comment: I will wait to award the bounty for now- just in case a better solution is posted (not that I'm expecting one, just being sure).